# How can I create custom csv from products

Tags: magento2, module, csv, export

I want to create custom export csv with products information in everyday.

Heads:

```
1. identifier;manufacturer;name;category;product_url;price;net_price;image_url;description;delivery_cost
2. ABC123;Example Manufact;Example Name;Animal > Anima sub category > Animals;http://example.com/example/example/example-name.html;180;141.73;http://example.com/media/catalog/product/e/g/egb_0356-1_2.jpg; lrem ipsum;990
3. ETC
```

I think I need a new module and setup a cronjob. Im a beginner, but I can do the instructions. So, how can I create a script runs every day? Please help me with link or codes and instructions.

Comment: Have you looked into a feed generator extension like https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/advanced-product-feeds.html ? but there are others. Depends how many feeds like this you need. Could save you a lot of time.

Comment: Nope. I'm interesting for a scrip/program solutions, but thanks for the tip.